# Receiving Credit Card Infomation from Card.Io

Tags: credit-card, card.io

noob here looking for help. When I use card.io to receive the user’s credit card information (type of card, card number, etc.) are there other 3rd party programs I can use to store this information so user’s can make a payment later?  Is it possible to do this with card.io? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Braintree's v.zero](https://www.braintreepayments.com/), which has the tokenization functionality you're looking for.